# Is there a way to know Vector3 in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
int resolution = 4;
Vector3 localUp = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
Vector3 axisA = new Vector3(localUp.y, localUp.z, localUp.x);
Vector3 axisB = Vector3.Cross(localUp, axisA);

int x = 1;
int y = 1;
Vector2 percent = new Vector2(x, y) / (resolution - 1);
Vector3 pointOnUnitCube = localUp + (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * axisA + (percent.y - .5f) * 2 * axisB;
```

I want to know the Object pointOnUnitCube and its properties but I dont know how to.

what does `pointOnUnitCube` refers to does it refer to:

```
new Vector3(localUp + (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * axisA + (percent.y - .5f) * 2 * axisB, localUp + (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * axisA + (percent.y - .5f) * 2 * axisB, localUp + (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * axisA + (percent.y - .5f) * 2 * axisB);
```

or this:

```
new Vector3(localUp + (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * axisA + (percent.y - .5f) * 2 * axisB, 0, 0);
```

which one and please help me and THANKS.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. You need to add a bit more context than a random snippet of code.

Comment: I want to know pointOnUnitCune properties.

Comment: what properties? [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) has a bunch of them

Comment: Can you not debug it and work out what it gives you?

Comment: I cant for some reason. I just want to know its pointOnUnitCune.x and pointOnUnitCune.y and pointOnUnitCune.z.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ToString.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it is a rather very generic question.

If you have two `Vector3`s `A` and `B`

```
var A = localUp;
var B = (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * axisA;
```

then [`A + B`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_add.html) results in a new vector with

```
new Vector3(A.x + B.x, A.y + B.y, A.z + B.z)
```

---

So in your case where you basically have `A + B + C` it will be equal to

```
var A = localUp;
var B = (percent.x - 0.5f) * 2 * axisA;
var C = (percent.y - 0.5f) * 2 * axisB;
var pointOnUnitCube  = new Vector3(A.x + B.x + C.x, A.y + B.y + C.y, A.z + B.z + C.z);
```